# Variable is null after setting it

Tags: react-native

I declare and initialize the variable like this

```
const [idOld, setIdOld] = useState(null)
```

Then when I call the function `testing()` on Button Press

```
const testing = () => {
        setIdOld(535)
        alert(idOld)
} 

return (
        <View>
            <Text>Home</Text>
            <CustomFloatingLogout bottom={80} onPress={() => testing()} />
            <CustomFloatingLogout onPress={() => logout()} />
        </View>
)
```

The alert shows the variable is null.

How to solve this?

Comment: `setState` in React Native is asynchronous, the change of state will not reflect immediately. If you would like to run functions after state changes, use `useEffect()` instead.

Comment: The problem has been solved. Thank you! @PeterTam

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the option is to utilize `useEffect` for it

```js
const [idOld, setIdOld] = useState(null)

useEffect(() => {
  alert(idOld)
}, [idOld]);


return (
        <View>
            <Text>Home</Text>
            <CustomFloatingLogout bottom={80} onPress={() => setIdOld(535)} />
            <CustomFloatingLogout onPress={() => logout()} />
        </View>
)
```

Comment: I want to set the variable after button click then use it @Isaac

Comment: Thanks I understood the use of useEffect. Solved it using your code and adding condition inside useEffect like this: useEffect(() => { if (idOld != null) {alert(idOld) setIdOld(null)} })